# Error: Can't access property href

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web

I am using NODE JS module with which I am creating a HTTP server. Server's response is a page containing JavaScript which embed a webpage in . 
Here is response code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function test() {
document.body.innerHTML='<iframe id="ifool" src="URL" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts"> </iframe>';
var c;                 
window.setInterval(function(){
c=document.getElementById("ifool").contentWindow.location.href; 
window.history.pushState(0,0,c);  
},100);
</script>
</head>
<body onload= "test()">
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Firebug with FF.I am getting following error:

```
 Error: Permission denied to access property 'href'
    c=document.getElementById("ifool").contentWindow.location.href;
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690598/permission-denied-to-access-property-in-iframe

Comment: It appears this can also be due to having Firebug open: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2910650/376789

Comment: Yes, I am using iframe

Comment: @jmar777: That answer is from 2010 … and I personally have never seen anything like this happen _only_ when Firebug was opened. Pretty sure it’s just the good old SOP …

Answer (score 3):

If the URL you are trying to access in your iframe is outside of your current page domain then you will not be able to do it. Modern browsers implement a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which decides the permissions of JavaScripts when running cross site scripting.

When a parent and child come from the same domain, they have access to each other; the child can access and operate properties and methods of the parent, and vice-versa. However, when they don't, attempting such access so will trigger script errors indicating Permission denied.

If I try running similar scripts with my page and iframe source pointing to pages hosted by node server, I get no permission errors.

Sources:

1. http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/iframe_talks_to_parent/
2. [error : Permission denied to access property 'document'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document)
3. [Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)
4. [<iframe> javascript access parent DOM across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)

Comment: This applies even if you are on the same server but you parent uses http://localhost/app1 and your iframe uses http://servername/app2 (this caught me out when debugging)